# Regex pattern definition implementation

Tags: c#, regex

My requirement is to design a part of a solution in such matter that specific placeholders are replaces dynamically with a defined logic and new rules can be easily added.

Simple example:

> Today is {today}. The year is {year}. Last year was {year-1}.

Should output something like:

> Today is 26 Jan 2018. The year is 2018. Last year was 2017.

There are several more business and context specific placeholders and new rules can follow frequently.

As such I came up with this class:

```
public class PlaceholderDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Pattern { get; }
    private readonly Func<Match, string> _logic;

    public PlaceholderDefinition(string name, string pattern, Func<Match, string> logic)
    {
        Name = name;
        Pattern = pattern;
        _logic = logic;
    }

    public string Apply(Match match) => _logic.Invoke(match);
}
```

To fulfill the above example, I register the following `PlaceholderDefinitions` in the service configuration:

```
RegisteredPlaceholders.Add(
    new PlaceholderDefinition(
        "Today",
        @"{[tT][oO][dD][aA][yY]}",
        (_) => DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()
    ));

RegisteredPlaceholders.Add(
    new PlaceholderDefinition(
        "Year",
        @"{[yY][eE][aA][rR]}",
        (_) => DateTime.Today.Year.ToString()
    ));

RegisteredPlaceholders.Add(
    new PlaceholderDefinition(
        "YearAddition",
        @"(?:{[yY][eE][aA][rR])([+-])(\d+)}",
        (m) =>
        {
            var operation = m.Groups[1].Value;
            int.TryParse(m.Groups[2].Value, out int value);
            return (operation == "+" ? DateTime.Today.Year + value : DateTime.Today.Year - value).ToString();
        }
    ));
```

The `RegisteredPlaceholders` is an enumerable of PlaceholderDefinition held in the container.

The logic of these patterns/placeholders is applied like this:

```
foreach (var placeholder in RegisteredPlaceholders)
 {
     var match = new Regex(placeholder.Pattern).Match(content);
     while (match.Success)
     {
         content = content.Remove(match.Index, match.Length).Insert(match.Index, placeholder.Apply(match));
         match = match.NextMatch();
     }
 }
```

I decided to take this approach instead of using `Regex.Replace()` to not reveal the content or text to the class defining the pattern logic. Maybe there is a more elegant solution, that I didn't come up with.

Every critique, improvement proposal, code smells are welcome.

Comment: `[tT][oO][dD][aA][yY]` - you know that you could just use the  `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, don't you?

Comment: I do but it applies to the complete pattern, in some matches case sensitivity is needed.

Comment: Why don't you just add another parameter to the `PlaceholderDefinition` that is of type `RegexOptions`?

Comment: that is a good idea, I will do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to use named group. As your pattern becomes more complex, it will get harder to maintain.

  ```
  @"(?:{[yY][eE][aA][rR])([+-])(\d+)}"
  var operation = m.Groups[1].Value;
  int.TryParse(m.Groups[2].Value, out int value);
  ```
- PlaceholderDefinition implementation requires way too much boilerplate code to use:

  ```
   foreach (var placeholder in RegisteredPlaceholders)
    {
        var match = new Regex(placeholder.Pattern).Match(content);
        while (match.Success)
        {
            content = content.Remove(match.Index, match.Length).Insert(match.Index, placeholder.Apply(match));
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
    }
  ```

  It could be boiled down to: `content = placeholder.Apply(text);`
- There is no need to use `Match.NextMatch` & `string.Remove`, when you can use `Regex.Replace`
- `_logic` seems to be a poorly chosen name. While it describes the essence, but not its concrete job. You should name `Func` with "Selector, factory, builder, ...", and prefix it with a noun ("result, replacement, ...") and the private member prefix `_` (if this is the convention, you choose to follow).

---

Modified `PlaceholderDefinition` class:

```
public class PlaceholderDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Regex Pattern { get; }

    private readonly Func<GroupCollection, object> _replacementSelector;

    public PlaceholderDefinition(string name, string pattern, Func<GroupCollection, object> replacementSelector)
         : this(name, new Regex(pattern), replacementSelector)
    {
    }
    public PlaceholderDefinition(string name, string pattern, RegexOptions options, Func<GroupCollection, object> replacementSelector)
         : this(name, new Regex(pattern, options), replacementSelector)
    {
    }
    public PlaceholderDefinition(string name, Regex pattern, Func<GroupCollection, object> replacementSelector)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Pattern = pattern;
        this._replacementSelector = replacementSelector;
    }

    public string Apply(string input) => Pattern.Replace(input, m => _replacementSelector(m.Groups).ToString());
}
```

There is various overloads of `ctor` to accommodate different needs, *like the one suggested by @t3chb0t*. Feels free to add more, if it help you to keep the declarations as clean as possible.

And, the rest of the code:

```
var text = "Today is {today}. The year is {year}. Last year was {year-1}.";
var placeholders = new List<PlaceholderDefinition>();
placeholders.Add(new PlaceholderDefinition("Today", @"{today}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, _ => DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()));
placeholders.Add(new PlaceholderDefinition("Year", @"{year}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, _ => DateTime.Today.Year));
placeholders.Add(new PlaceholderDefinition(
    "YearAddition", 
    @"{year(?<sign>[+-])(?<value>\d+)}",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, 
    g => DateTime.Today.Year + int.Parse(g["sign"].Value + g["value"].Value)
));

foreach (var placeholder in placeholders)
{
    text = placeholder.Apply(text);
}
```

---

- The `_replacementSelector` takes in `GroupCollection`, so we can skip writing `m => m.Group...`, and the `object` TResult allows us to skip the necessary `.ToString()` or a parenthesis on binary operation.
- `int.Parse` will parse number prefixed by a `+` sign as positive number, allowing us to skip the ternary operation.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. These are some great suggestions.